# Problem with animation-fill-mode in Firefox 75

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with `animation-fill-mode` on FF 75.

---

In the code snippet (at https://codepen.io/simplebinary/pen/JjYzKwr), the animation runs but returns to the default state after the animation is finished, prefixes don't fix the problem.

Edit: Thanks to @temani-afif

Fixed code is here: https://codepen.io/simplebinary/pen/KKdjYvY

Comment: `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` should be After the animation not before

Comment: Of course. Little mistakes. 

Comment: now that you have fixed your codepen, the question is irrelevant and will get closed .. unless you bring your faulty code again inside the question (or remove the question)